# Check whether word exists in database and if true output data from neighbouring column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table. One column is words and the other is id numbers. I have a list of words in an array. I need to check whether the words are similar, then if so I need to output the word's id from table. Could anyone help?
So I'm checking whether it's similar, but can't find ways what to do next

```
  $checkTag = "SELECT `word`, `wordid` FROM `qa_words` WHERE `word` = '.$allTags[$i].'";
         $CheckResult = mysql_query($checkTag);
         if(mysql_num_rows($CheckResult) > 0){
          while ( $obj = mysql_fetch_object( $CheckResult)){

          echo ...
}}
```

Comment: So i'm cheking with "if" as above, but it's giving error: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

Comment: `$checkTag` is query. you need to pass that in `mysql_query()` and its result should be passed in `mysql_num_rows()`. AND START using `MySQLi` or `PDO MySQL`, `mysql` extension will be removed soon.

Comment: @Jigar Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: can you update the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to actually perform the query, additionally you need to wrap your array variable in {}.

```
mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_password ) or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db( $db_name ) or die( mysql_error() );

$checkTag = "SELECT `id`, `word` FROM `qa_words` WHERE `word` = '{$allTags[$i]}'";
$result = mysql_query( $checkTag ) or die( mysql_error() );
if ( @mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
    // conditions if true
    while ( $obj = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) )
    {
        echo $obj->id . ': ' . $obj->word . '<br />';
    }
}
```

you could also concatenate the query:

```
$checkTag = "SELECT `word` FROM `qa_words` WHERE `word` = '" . $allTags[$i] . "'";
```

Comment: No luck: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in if line

Comment: revised. try it now after adding `die( mysql_error() )` so you can see what error is being thrown in your query. additionally, i added `@mysql_num_rows()` to suppress the PHP warning when the query fails (which results in NO rows).  you have a mistake in your query somewhere.

Comment: also, make sure you are checking mysql_num_rows on the RESULT of your query and NOT your query string `$result = mysql_query( $checkTag )` then `mysql_num_rows( **$result** )` and NOT `mysql_num_rows( $checkTag )`

Comment: it's showing: No database selected . How so? I'm getting $allTags array from db as well

Comment: are you switching databases anywhere in your code? because you have to switch back and forth each time you want to perform a query unless you use 'db_name.table.column' queries. you need a `mysql_connect()` and a `mysql_select_db()` call. can you confirm you are making a connection and then selecting the db after that?

Comment: I figured out connection, thanks. But can't get the data from table.    `$checkTag = "SELECT `word`, `wordid` FROM `qa_words` WHERE `word` = 'abc'";` by this i'm getting a row with "abc", if it's correct how i can get word id for "abc"

Answer (score 0):

Check following code

```
    $check = "SELECT `id`, `word` FROM `qa_words` WHERE `word` = '{$allTags[$i]}'";

$result = mysql_query( $check );
if (!( mysql_num_rows( $result )<= 0 )) {
    // conditions if true
    while ( $obj = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) )
    {
        echo $obj->id . ': ' . $obj->word . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: this differs from the example only by suppressing the `mysql_num_rows()` warning